# How to capture data and send to server API using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular for the first time and and running into problems while sending simple data back to the server.

I have a server running at API: `http://localhost:8080/takepayment` which accepts `POST` request and expects a `tokenId`.

My JS looks like this and is successfully getting a token back from Stripe. I simply want to send this token to the above API url as a `POST` request.

How can I do this in Angular?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp')
.controller('TakeMoneyCtrl', function ($scope, djangoAuth, Validate) {
  $scope.complete = false;
  djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data){
    $scope.model = data;
  });
  $scope.handleStripe = function(status, response){
    if(response.error) {
      // there was an error. Fix it.
      alert("error")
    } else {
      // got stripe token, now charge it or smt
      token = response.id
      alert("success: " +token);
    }
  }
});
```

I want to send the token to the server only when I successfully get the token back from Stripe. So I put an `alert("success");` there but even that alert isn't showing on the page. Neither is `alert("error");` showing. However, on network tab of chrome I can see that `token` is in fact coming back from stripe.

**Question**

How can I send the token fetched from Stripe to my API call on `http://localhost:8080/takepayment` as a `POST` request/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of the Angular `$http` service ([Docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)). Inject it and then consume it in your controller. Here's a simple example that consumes the Angular `$http` service and does a `POST`.

```
angular.module('angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp')
.controller('TakeMoneyCtrl', ['$http', function ($scope, $http, djangoAuth, Validate) {
  $scope.complete = false;
  djangoAuth.profile().then(function(data){
    $scope.model = data;
  });
  $scope.handleStripe = function(status, response){
    if(response.error) {
      // there was an error. Fix it.
      alert("error")
    } else {
      // got stripe token, put it in an object then use it in $http.post
      var dataModel = {
         token: response.id
      };

     //You can do your $http post here OR preferably in Seperate Service.
     $http.post('/someUrl', JSON.stringify(dataModel)).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });

      alert("success: " +token);
    }
  }
}]);
```

The above is one way to do it. But its best to move the `$http` call into a separate Angular Service and possibly make use of JS Promises to wait for a response or a timeout to occur. Here's an example of a Service and the use of Promises to do a HTTP Post.

**Creating a new Angular Service to handle $http**

```
var app = angular.module('angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp', []);
app.service('CommService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.processLoginToken = function(token) {
        var model = {
            token: token
        };

        var promise = $http.post('/api/tokenproc', JSON.stringify(model))
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;

            }, function(error) {
               console.log("Communication error, server did not reply.");
            });

        return promise;
    };
```

**Now outside your service, you would use it like this.**

```
   var token = "02394924924929424";
   CommService.processLoginToken(token)
    .then(function (response) {
           //Process your response.data here
        }, function () {
           //Server didn't respond.
    });
```